# Web Services and Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Was this good combination for web development in Asp.Net C#

Security?
Performance?

if not could you please recommend something that is best to use

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I would suggest you to read the difference and decide by yourself

Web Service:

1) It is a SOAP based service and returns data as XML.

2) It only supports the HTTP protocol.

3) It can only be hosted on IIS.

4) It is not open source, but can be used by any client that understands XML.

5) It requires a SOAP protocol to receive and send data over the network, so it is not a light-weight architecture.

Web API:

1) A Web API is a HTTP based service and returns JSON or XML data by default.

2) It supports the HTTP protocol.

3) It can be hosted within an application or IIS.

4) It is open source and it can be used by any client that understands JSON or XML.

5) It is light-weight architectured and good for devices which have limited bandwidth, like mobile devices.
[image]

Comment: asmx web services return json by default and have for a long time.